# How to utilize three-phase electrical in residential garage for antique shop equipment

Tags: phase, equipment

I hope this message finds you well.  Please explain how to utilize three-phase electrical in residential garage for antique shop equipment.  The power company will NOT dig new lines for true 3-phase.  What would be the most cost efficient method for hooking up these older machines?  They run on 220V and max 5HP. Thank you kindly

Comment: I forget what it's called, but you can get a converter device which consists of a single-phase motor driving a 3-phase alternator. Alternatively a 3-phase UPS (with at least halfway decent sinewave output) may work.

Comment: @brhans, I believe you're thinking of phase converters.

Comment: This is off topic here.  Consult a home shop machining forum for *practical* advice on Vector Frequency Drives, rotary phase converters, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are various types of phase converters available. There are do-it-yourself methods involving an "idler" three-phase motor and some capacitors. There are variable frequency drives (VFDs) that convert 230 V, single-phase to 230 V, 3-phase and also provide motor speed control. There are also VFDs that convert 120 V single-phase to 230 V, 3-phase, but they would probably only do 2 or 3 Hp. There are do-it-yourself methods that require only capacitors connected to the motors that you have, but they will reduce the power capability of your motors. It is probably best to look for recommendations on metal and wood shop hobbyist sites.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

This from the the practical machinist site , which is better suited to answer your situation.

REF  http://www.practicalmachinist.com/vb/transformers-phase-converters-and-vfd/rotary-phase-converter-designs-plans-101231/index9.html

If you can't afford a good system, expect motor stalls, breaker trips and sluggish load response for peak torque loads, which depends on how much of your motor capacity you need.  Motor start surge current can be >5 times max rated current.

(ask how much to dig for 3phase.)